# C++ incorrect output

Tags: c++, output

I wrote simple program on C++

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    int   number19 , number20  ;
    const int number = 10 ;
    number20 = number + 10 ;
    number19 = number20--;
    cout << number << endl;
    cout << number20 << endl;
    cout << number19 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think that output should be:
10
20
19
But output is
10
19
20

Why I get such  output ?

Comment: do you know the difference between post and pre- decrement?

Comment: Output is correct. Why you expected different output? Maybe you did output the numbers in different order than you wanted because of typo?

Comment: `10 19 20` is the correct result here. `number20` gets decremented before printing, but `number19` contains the original value before the decrement, since you're using a post-decrement.

Comment: With pre-decrement the result would be 10 19 19 so the issue is not about difference between pre- and post- decrement.

Comment: I'm  new in C++ but as I know there is no differences  between  post and pre- decrement , it decrease number on 1.

Comment: To subtract 1 from a variable without changing it, you need `x - 1`, not `x--` or `--x`.

Comment: @Ilya Think about it: if there was no difference, why would two separate operations exist?

Comment: @KonradRudolph That logic is a touch ironic, given we're discussing C++. There is significant overlap in the many different ways to initialize, for example.

Comment: @sweenish I realise that but even C++ isn't moronic enough to provide two distinct operators to do the exact same thing (well, it actually does: `and`/`&&` etc. … ok, you were right, I’ll shut up).

Answer (score 4):

There is a rather large difference between pre- and post-increment and decrement.

The pre-decrement returns the *new* value, while post-decrement returns the *old* value.

That means you statement

```
number19 = number20--;
```

is really equivalent to something like:

```
{
    int old_number20 = number20;
    number20 = number20 - 1;

    number19 = old_number20;
}
```

Any decent beginners learning resource should have had that information.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to understand how the decrement operators work.

```
number19 = number20--;
```

is doing something different than

```
number19 = number20 - 1;
```

where the latter seems to be what you expect.

Briefly `number20--` is an expression that actually changes the value of the variable `number20` but evaluates to the original value whereas `number20 - 1` is an expression that just returns the value of the expression without touching the variable.

There is also another form of decrement, `--number20`, that will change the value of the variable and evaluate to the *new* value.